# Lua regex for ascii(0-127) characters

Tags: regex, lua, hex, ascii

I am using LUA and trying to replace non ascii characters in some input string.
I used the `[^\x00–\x7F]` regex but getting the following error:
malformed pattern (missing ']')
Also I used    `[^[:ascii:]]` but it is does not work.
I think that    `[^\x00–\x7F]` is the right way but I am probably missing some escape.
Please help!

Comment: To replace or remove? Try `string.gsub(s, "[^\000-\127]", "")`

Comment: To replace: `string.gsub(jsonReport, "[^\000-\127]", "?")`. I tried your suggestion: stiil getting :  malformed pattern (missing ']')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace non-ascii characters:

```
string.gsub(your_string, "[\128-\255]", what_they_should_be_replaced_with)
```

Alternative way:

```
string.gsub(your_string, "[^%z\1-\127]", what_they_should_be_replaced_with)
```

For UTF-8 texts:

```
string.gsub(your_string, "[\192-\255][\128-\191]*", what_they_should_be_replaced_with)
```

Comment: This `"[^%z\1-\127]"` does not seem to work well for replacing, see https://ideone.com/RZ1CvZ. Do you know why it replaces one `§` with 2 `^`s?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Because UTF-8 symbol `§` is stored as two bytes.

Comment: That is what I understood, but how to replace one `§` with one `^`?

Comment: It seems to work fine. But some how the non-ascii characters replaced with ?? and not with ?, but it is still ok for me.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, Thanks a lot!